# Android USB audio recording not working in samsung Tab S

Tags: android, audio, usb

I am working on audio recording app through external USB Microphone. It works fine(records audio from USB mic) with Motorola devices(Moto g running lollipop) , but in Samsung Tab S (lollipop) audio is getting recorded from inbuilt Microphone only.

I am using audioRecord class for the recording

```
int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(44100,
        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
byte[] mBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
AudioRecord mRecorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
        44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);
if (AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED == mRecorder.getState()) {
    mRecorder.startRecording();
}
```

Is there any way to switch Audio source from inbuilt mic to USB mic, so that it works in Samsung as well.

Thanks.

Comment: I am also facing same issue in Samsung S5 device, have you got any solution for this ? If you got please post the answer.